# How to record a video in Selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, video-recording

I have automated scripts that run every night (around 350 scripts or testcases). I want to record a video of each test case (Python scripts). Is there a tool or way that I can use to control video recording for each test case separately?

For instance, during a test case setup start recording and during teardown stop recording and save the video locally with a specified name and date. So I should have 350 videos for each testcase (more preferably save only videos for the failed test cases).

Is there a way of integrating this functionality in the code I use for my setups and teardowns?

Comment: http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/blog/2010/castro-selenium-video.html

Comment: Do you really need a video, when it is trivially easy to [take a ScreenShot][1]?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver

Comment: Yes I use screenshots already but som test cases fail during the nightly runs without any help from the screenshot. I need to see what happens prior to the moment of failure not the failure itself

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple webdriver has no function to record video; you need to use a third-party library, like [Castro](https://pypi.org/project/castro/)(only support python 2).

For a Java webdriver, look at blog post *[Screen Recording (Video) of Java Webdriver script](http://roadtoautomation.blogspot.in/2013/03/screen-recording-video-of-java-webdiver.html)*.

Comment: Is there something for the C# or .Net world?

Comment: It does not support python 3

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Castro](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/castro/) in Python...

Comment: is there any way for doing same using Java

Comment: Unfortunately Castro only supports Python 2.7 which is already sunset by python.org
It has not been ported to Python 3 and proven to work.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following web service http://bit.ly/video-recorder-service which can be remotely controlled with simple http requests.

I have used this for webdriver tests in a grid environment.