# How to record video with Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, video, gif, record

I want to record a video of a few seconds (or gif) of a web page, I tried to take screenshots but the problem is that selenium takes too much time to make them (5 in 2 seconds). So I'm looking for a way to shoot the page.

I didn't find any recent tool, in fact the only programs doing it are on python2.

If someone has a way, I'm interested!

Comment: You can use Castro in Python... https://github.com/hugs/castro

Comment: this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706225/how-to-record-a-video-in-selenium-webdriver

Comment: Castro is for python2 and I want to work to raspberry pi
I have an error when I try to use it:
  File "/home/pi/PokemonBot/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from castro import Castro
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/castro/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    import lib.messageboard as mb
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib.messageboard'